# RewriteRule depending on HTTP_REFERER and REMOTE_ADDR

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect users to a specific page if they are not coming from a specific IP and if they are requesting a specific domain.

I tried :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^hello\.example\.com [NC] # the user requested https://hello.example.com
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.99 # the user's IP is not 123.456.789.99
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC] # the user is not already on the redirected page
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

But it does not work...

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTP_REFERER` contains the *referring* URL (the contents of the `Referer` HTTP request header, ie. the URL the user is coming *from*), not the domain being requested. For that you need to test against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable (ie. the `Host` HTTP request header) instead.

Note also that Apache does not support line-end comments - your second *condition* (as written) would result in a 500 Internal Server Error due to an invalid flags argument.

There is no need for the 3rd condition that checks that the requested URL is not `/maintenance.html` as this can more efficiently be checked in the `RewriteRule` itself.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hello\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.99$
RewriteRule !maintenance\.html$ /maintenance.html [NC,R=302,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

*Aside:* For checking single IP addresses, it is often easier/cleaner to use a lexicographical string comparison (using the `=` prefix operator), rather than a regex. For example:

```
:
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.456.789.99
:
```

---

However, if you are implementing a temporary "under maintenance" page then consider sending a 503 Service Unavailable response instead.

Reference:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/website-is-under-maintenance-how-to-restrict-access
- See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536055/369434) to the following SO question: [How to keep website url the same in .htaccess 503 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66530827/how-to-keep-website-url-the-same-in-htaccess-503-redirect)